# excel vba UDF executing 3 times when used in formula

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I would like to know how I can prevent my UDF to execute 3 times when used as a formula.

Excel 2013 (build: 15.0.4859.1002)

I built a User defined Function that must validate a set of two values against an excel ListObject named "table_Sequence".
If the values exist, the function returns the corresponding letter.

So basically, I'm trying to create a tool that will help us build our SAP FLOC structure based on certain rules.  One of which, Level 5 is 3 digits code that contains a reference number that comes from tab "5- Function list" and a unique letter for every Customtext entered in tab Equipements, column 'M'.

So my idea was to first check if the key already exist, and if not, create it in table_Sequence.

The code works fine.

But...  **It runs three times every time I update a cell using that UDF**!!!
So I am afraid that if a user wants to copy this formula throughout the column it will create a terrible lag whenever dependencies are updated.

Can someone help me understand what's going on and how I can prevent this?

Any help will be appreciated,

table_Sequence looks like this:

```
Struct             |CustomText  |Letter
----------------   |------      |---
2151-05-01-22-23   |#1 L1       |B
2151-05-01-22-86   |#2 L1       |A
```

So in a cell I call the UDF like this:

```
=GetNextSequence("2151-05-01-22-23";"#1 L1")
```

And it returns "B" which is good.
Only it executes 3 times before it gets the result back

Here's the UDF code:

```
'**************************************************************************************************
'**     Name:       GetNextSequence
'**     Purpose:    Assign next sequence for current structure element
'**
'**     Input:      Current Cell
'**                 Level Number at which we may stop the structure
'**
'**     Output:     Sequence string
'**
'**************************************************************************************************
Public Function GetNextSequence(Struct As String, CustomText As String) As String

Dim i As Long
Dim Result As Variant
Dim suffix As String
Dim NewRow As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'** Filter and sort sequence table
Set tbl = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sequence").ListObjects("table_Sequence")
tbl.Sort.SortFields.Clear
tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("table_Sequence_1[Letter]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With tbl.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Struct
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=CustomText
'** Store Last letter used
suffix = tbl.ListRows(1).Range.Cells(1, 3).Value

If tbl.ListRows.Count = 0 Then
    '** Increment sequence
    suffix = Chr(Asc(suffix) + 1)
    '** Add row and return new letter
    Set NewRow = tbl.ListRows.Add.Range
    iColumn = tbl.ListColumns("Letter").Index
    NewRow.Cells(1, 3).Value = suffix
    NewRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = Struct
    NewRow.Cells(1, 2).Value = CustomText

End If

GetNextSequence = suffix

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: [Please edit your question to include the relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41128718/edit).  Not many people are going to (should) download and open a random macro enabled Excel file, and assuming they would, this question doesn't help anyone else with a similar issue if the link goes dead.

Comment: There are many that will not download a macro enabled workbook from a public forum.  Please include the code and describe how you are using it in the Original post.

Comment: I'm not downloading your macro-enabled virus, and nobody should. That's not how this site works.

Comment: Thanks all, makes a lot of sense.  I just updated the post with relevant info.  Let me know if I should post more.

Comment: At this point it might be a better idea to delete this question, read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and ask it again, this time including all the relevant info on the first go. :)

Comment: I think you will need to include the code of the function, not just show how it is called.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, I realized that right after I posted the update.

Comment: I'm scratching my head now - I wouldn't have thought that a UDF would have been able to insert new data into a table.  Maybe this is another loophole that **does** allow a UDF to update more than the current cell.

Comment: @YowE3K: It might explains all the crashes I experience and loosing  input parameter's value during execution...  Excel is really surprising these days... In all means possible!

Comment: Yes I'm amazed if that works at all as a UDF.  As for multiple executions - that is not uncommon and is covered by Charles Williams here: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm

Comment: Can you please reopen the question?

Comment: I just tried running it with your sample table.  I had to modify `"table_Sequence_1[Letter]"` to `"table_Sequence[Letter]"` before it would work.  (I assume the table is called `table_Sequence`.)  The code ran once and returned `"B"`.

Comment: @Tim Williams: What would be a good practice to achieve this without using a UDF?

Comment: FWIW - The code that I suspected would kill a UDF can't actually be executed - `If tbl.ListRows.Count = 0 Then` is preceded by a statement which accesses `tbl.ListRows(1)` so that statement would crash before the `If` block could be executed.  (I'm rather surprised that the `Sort` works but I guess that is somewhat acceptable behaviour.)

Comment: @Firefighter1017 - if the code "works" you can call it from a Sub as long as you can create a suitable trigger (a button or maybe an event) to kick off the sub.

Comment: You use `Field3` in one of your filters - it should be `Field2`.  And `suffix = tbl.ListRows(1).Range.Cells(1, 3).Value` doesn't return the first **visible** row (so you will always be returning `"B"` at the moment).

Comment: @YowE3K: Just stumbled upon this last statement of yours... I guess I'll have to figure out how I can determine if the filters have selected any rows.  Thanks, I didn't figure this one out until I read and understood what you were saying

Answer (score 0):

For those needing closure on this issue,

I gave up trying to use a UDF to retreive proper code.
I simply created triggers on WorkSheet.Change and WorkSheet.BeforeDoubleClick events.

If you need me to post the code and data let me know.

Thanks YowE3K and Tom Williams for their help.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for those who voted negative, it really gives me a sense that my contribution counts.  ... not really...